# Filtering Dates in FireDac TTable

Tags: mysql, delphi, date, firedac

I'm having a problem using TTable in FireDac to filter on a date field.

The database in MySQL/InnoDB. The field is of type Date.

The code I am using to set the filter is

```
Filter := 'date = ' + QuotedStr(FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy', Date));
Filtered := True;
```

Every time I either get an error when setting the filter: "EConvertError with message 'Could not parse SQL TimeStamp string'" or the filter fails to find any records.

The above format is for my current regional settings. I've also tried 'yyyy-mm-dd'. And I've tried both both with and without quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I spend three hours on this and immediately after I ask the question I find an answer. Use [Preprocessor Commands](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)):

```
Filter := 'date = {d ' + (FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Date))+'}';
```

Comment: FireDAC preprocessor commands are useful for producing SQL code while remaining agnostic about the RDBMS. Filters should use a standard format, maybe similar to standard SQL, so I think you just got lucky ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat.

Example:

```
Filter := 'date = ' + QuotedStr(FormatDateTime(FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat, Date));
```